# A funny problem in Rider when I'm coding in Rider (C#)

Tags: c#, jetbrains-ide, rider

I was trying to print "I like pizza." in Rider, but it printed "Hello, World!"

Does anyone know why?

[image]
*(I'm using MacBook Air)*

I tried for a lot of times but still failed.

Comment: What is in your Program.cs file?

Comment: You need to add code to Main method in Program.cs file.

Comment: A project can have just one `Main` method as entry point (and top-level statements also count as entry point). Try and remove Program.cs

Answer (score 1):

You should check your **program.cs** file.

Probably it looks like this:

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

More explanation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates